# How write query for join two tables without nulls?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, null, case

I have 2 tables

Airport

```
+ -------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
| ID                                   | IATA        | ICAO        | 
+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
| 01d491eb-7d00-410c-9c19-eb23d83f9c65 | CHH         | SPPY        | 
+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

AirportTranslation

```
+ -------------------------------------+------------------------------------ -+------+-------------+
| ID                                   | PARENTID                             | LANG | VALUE       |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| 01d491eb-7d00-410c-9c19-eb23d83f9c66 | 01d491eb-7d00-410c-9c19-eb23d83f9c65 | ESP  | CHACHAPOYAS |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| eb06eb88-0530-4051-b4eb-3a04a01bcafe | 01d491eb-7d00-410c-9c19-eb23d83f9c65 | ENG  | CHACHAPOYAS |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

Following query return simple join:

```
SELECT
public."Airports"."ID",
public."Airports"."IATA", 
public."Airports"."ICAO",
CASE WHEN public."AirportTranslation"."Lang" = 'ESP' THEN public."AirportTranslation"."Value" ELSE null END as "ESP",
CASE WHEN public."AirportTranslation"."Lang" = 'EN' THEN public."AirportTranslation"."Value" ELSE null END as "EN"
FROM public."Airports" JOIN 
public."AirportTranslation" ON
```

result looks like:

```
+ -------------------------------------+-----+------+-------------+-----------+
| ID                                   | ITA | ICAO | ESP         | EN        |
+--------------------------------------+-----+--------------------+-----------+
| 01d491eb-7d00-410c-9c19-eb23d83f9c65 | CHH | SPPY | null        |CHACHAPOYAS|
+--------------------------------------+-----+--------------------+-----------+
| 01d491eb-7d00-410c-9c19-eb23d83f9c65 | CHH | SPPY | CHACHAPOYAS |null       |
+--------------------------------------+-----+------|-------------+-----------+
```

Is possible to write query for getting  result without nulls and without using WITH, crosstab etc?

```
+ -------------------------------------+-----+------+-------------+-----------+
| ID                                   | ITA | ICAO | ESP         | EN        |
+--------------------------------------+-----+--------------------+-----------+
| 01d491eb-7d00-410c-9c19-eb23d83f9c65 | CHH | SPPY | CHACHAPOYAS |CHACHAPOYAS|
+--------------------------------------+-----+--------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can `GROUP BY` and use `case` _expressions_ to do _conditional aggregation_ for each language.

Comment: @jarlh  Thaks for answer. Which aggregation function should be used?

Comment: MAX() or MIN().